# Should /var/lib/grafana be checked into version control for persistance?

Tags: git, docker, github, grafana

For my project I setup a grafana container which runs my application and monitors it. To safe all the dashboards and datasources I added /var/lib/grafana to a docker volume checked it into version control and pushed it to github. I wanna know if this is good practice and what would be a better option. As I understood there is no global config file for grafana so making a backup of the whole /var/lib/grafana folder is the only option. Is there any better way of doing that? I basically want that everyone who clones and executes the project gets the same grafana dashboard with the same sources etc.

Answer (score 0):

Figured out the answer. I was wrong, there are concrete configuration files.
This is a good resource to get started (https://keepgrowing.in/tools/grafana-provisioning-how-to-configure-data-sources-and-dashboards/). Sadly you can't generate config files for datasources, so you have to write them yourself... But you can create dashboards in the webinterface and the export them to json.

Comment: Update for anyone who is interested, there is a third-party tool that can export existing datasources from grafana: https://github.com/trivago/hamara